# Update an installed android apk using another apk without google play

Tags: android, installation, google-play, apk, updates

I have a deployed an android app which has not been uploaded to Google Play according to the requirement of the client. I want to update the apk without uploading to Google Play and keeping the existing data of the current app. Is there a possibility to update the installed apk using a new apk by the device?

Thank you

Comment: How do you save your data?

Comment: As preferences and in a SQLite database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the updated .apk from your server through your app, then you can install the `apk` through action Intent.

For more detail on how to install the apk from app refer the following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969421/1405008